# opencv 2.4.7 with visual 2010

Tags: opencv

Can anyone give me the link to download opencv 2.4.7 or any other version compatible with visual studio 2010? I have tried to include latest version library (3.2) in VS2010 but it isn't compatible with VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

http://4someonehelp.blogspot.in/2013/06/solved-install-opencv-245-using-visual.html

```
Install OpenCV 2.4.7 using Visual Studio 2010 / 2012 in Windows 7 / 8 (FOR 64 bit machine only)
```

And You Can Download It From Here !!

https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/

Comment: http://ay.gy/ZpZF1   OR  https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/       --- Download From Here